# Как можно разместить форму отправки вопроса в сетке бутстрапа?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bootstrap

Есть код сетки бутстрапа :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 .col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 ">
        <div class = "WhiteFigure WhiteFigure1"></div> //строка на замену
        <p class="textQuastionDown">почта</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 .col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 ">
        <div class = "WhiteFigure WhiteFigure2"></div> //строка на замену
        <p class="textQuastionDown">твой вопрос</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

и форма обратной связи :

```
<form>

    <!-- Hidden Required Fields -->
    <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="SketchBook">
    <input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="selin@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="Question">
    <!-- END Hidden Required Fields -->

    <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Ваша почта" required><br> //нужно вместо первой строки на замену 
    <input type="text" name="E-mail" placeholder="Ваш вопрос" required><br> //нужно вместо второй строки на замену 
    <button>Send</button>

  </form>
```

Мне нужно чтобы мои *инпуты* стояли вместо "строки на замену" . Если я просто сделаю две такие формы то оно будет выполнятся два раза и мне будет отравляться два письма .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form>
    <!-- Hidden Required Fields -->
    <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="SketchBook">
    <input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="selin@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="Question">
    <!-- END Hidden Required Fields -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 .col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 ">
                <div class = "WhiteFigure WhiteFigure1"><input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Ваша почта" required></div>
                <p class="textQuastionDown">почта</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 .col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 ">
                <div class = "WhiteFigure WhiteFigure2"><input type="text" name="E-mail" placeholder="Ваш вопрос" required></div>
                <p class="textQuastionDown">твой вопрос</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button>Send</button>
</form>
```